# How to get input values by using querySelectorAll in puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I have input fields in my project. I want to automate putting values in them with puppeteer. The input fields do not have `id`, `name`. Additionally, I cannot take `className` as `className` is also used by others elements.

Here is the input field:

```html
<input type="text" data-bind="value: NeedleOut" class="box-short">
```

I tried the following code but it is not working:

```js
await page.$eval("input[data-bind='value: NeedleOut']", ele1 => {
    ele1[0].value = 5;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [docs](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevalselector-pagefunction-args-1) `$eval` returns a single element - you should replace `ele1[0]` with `ele1` or use `$$eval` instead.

Comment: await page.$$eval("input[data-bind=value: NeedleOut]",el=>{
            console.log(el[0].value);
        })
this does not work

Comment: after putting single quotes  it works thank you.                                                       await page.$$eval("input[data-bind='value: NeedleOut '] ",el=>{ console.log(el[0].value); })